# How do I run Counter-Strike 1.6 in Zombie mode?

Tags: counter-strike

Can someone explain in detail how to run Counter-Strike 1.6 in zombie mode?

Comment: First, there are maaaaaany zombie mods. Second, what did you try already? Third, did you even try googling? And last, check [this link](http://bit.ly/1j32XLO)

Comment: @Novarg What are you talking about? As far as I know, there is only one Zombie mod out there, which is ZPlague.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most recommended way of using add-ons is by running them on top of AMX MOD X. This is a system which runs on Counter-Strike and allows for plugins to be installed.

1. You need to setup and install [AMX MOD X](http://www.amxmodx.org/downloads.php).
2. Now, you need to download the actual plugin. You coud use: [Allied Modders - Zombie MOD](https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=72505). If you are unsure of what to install where, both archives should be extracted **inside** the **cstrike** or **czero** directory.

   - [Zombie MOD](https://forums.alliedmods.net/attachment.php?attachmentid=93051&d=1316978741).
   - [Zombie MOD Resources](https://forums.alliedmods.net/attachment.php?attachmentid=28817&d=1216059497).

Now just start a server and this should work.

Comment: let's use this tonight :P